# Call Specific Column In Array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have some array like this 
When I use code like this :

> I got this error : Notice: Undefined index: users_id in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\home\database\index.php on line 21

I want to call specific columns like : users_id , users_username ,etc.

If I use :

```
var_dump ($rowset);
```

I got :

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [users_id] => 1 [users_username] => admin [users_password] => admin
```

My Code :

```
$rowset = array();
    while ($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){  `enter code here`
        $rowset[] = $row;
    }
        echo $rowset["users_id"];// Line 21
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: What do you need to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once try like this,

```
foreach($rowset as $k => $v){
 echo $rowset[$k]["users_id"];
}
```

Comment: Then i got just one users_id

Comment: then use foreach, check answer again

Comment: :D This message is for you, :p DO it after six minutes.

Answer (score 0):

you may make use of the pretty [array_column](http://php.net/array_column) :

```
$user_ids = array_column($rowset, 'users_id');
```